# Switches without SFP and with SFP

Tags: networking, switch, sfp

So I am looking at two different rackmount switches, one I do not have SFP ports on there and one that does. Would it be possible to have those two switches linked up through just looping through ports on the switch or is the SFP trunking is mandatory?

Comment: Please provide the device models.

Answer (score 0):

"Would it be possible to have those two switches linked up through just looping through ports on the switch or is the SFP trunking is mandatory?"

Yes it would and no trunking isn't mandatory - though both of these answers are for a simple flat design, I can think of a number of more complex designs that would require different answers.